# Python progroam, Exclude Groups

Tags: python, for-loop

```
    kicked = 0

    def calculate():
        room = 0
        global kicked
        
        N = input("Write the number of groups\n")
        M = input("Write the size of the groups, separated with space:\n").split()
        for elem in M:
            if room+int(elem)<int(N)+1:
                room += int(elem)
            else:
                kicked += 1
                
    while True:
        try:
            calculate()
            print(kicked, "groups did not fit")
            break
        except:
            print("An exception occurred, try again:\n")
```

Mainly I need help to explain my for loop.
secondly I can't use a splitter input on my first input, why?

Comment: Asking for help "to explain my for loop" is a bit unusual - it's _your_ loop, you should know what it does :D Anyhow it basically checks if the sum of all elements in M insofar is still less than or equal to N; if not it "kicks" every remaining elements. Not the most efficient way to do that, but it works. For the second question: you surely can use `split()` on your first input, but you will get a `list`, not a single value - so you will need to do something like `int(N[0]) to get the number

Comment: Thank you so much bro. You said it's not the most efficient way, so how would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

Transforming the previous comment into an answer, and adding some optimization hints that would not fit in a comment:

Asking for help "to explain my for loop" is a bit unusual - it's *your* loop, you should know what it does :D Anyhow it basically checks if the sum of all elements in `M` insofar is still less than or equal to `N`; if not it "kicks" every remaining elements. Not the most efficient way to do that, but it works. For the second question: you surely can use `split()` on your first input, but you will get a list, not a single value - so you will need to do something like `int(N[0])` to get the number.

Optimizations:

- casting a string to an int is not particularly slow, but there is no need to repeat the same operation many times. So let's convert `N` to int once and for all:

```
N = int(input("Write the number of groups\n"))
```

- for the same reason, let's convert each `elem` to int once, not twice, and while we're here let's test for less or equal instead of adding 1 and testing for less than (this last point will only give a very slight improvement but improves readability):

```
for elem in M:
    e = int(elem)
    if room + e <= int(N):
        room += e
```

- finally once we kick a group there's no need to continue looping - we are kicking everything else. So let's compute how many groups we are kicking and exit the loop:

```
for i,elem in enumerate(M):
    e = int(elem)
    if room + e <= int(N):
        room += e
    else:
        kicked = len(M) - i
        break
```